# Data Type for duration/time - values in Directus

Tags: sqldatatypes, directus

I'ld like to store duration(time)-values, e.g." 1 h, 30 m".
Is there any "time-type" or do I have to store the value in seconds and use anything like DATETIME to convert into the desired format?

The datetime-Datatype is not useful since it is for date and 12/24 hour time values

Answer (score 0):

All sql DB has Time type, use Time type.
(Can this read as DateTime. MySQL,Postgre,MSSQL,Oracle etc.
If you need nanosecound, must you have to search by database type.